# How to stretch elements equally on RelativePanel?

Tags: xaml, winui-3

How can I stretch the rectangles beneath equally, so that in the first row half-half, in the second row, 1/3 1/3 1/3 allocated ?

```
<RelativePanel>
    <Rectangle Fill="Blue" Margin="5" x:Name="Pm25" MinHeight="100" MinWidth="100" RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"/>
    <Rectangle Fill="Blue" Margin="5" x:Name="Pm10" MinHeight="100" MinWidth="100" RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True"/>

    <Rectangle Fill="Blue" Margin="5" x:Name="O3" RelativePanel.Below="Pm25" MinHeight="100" MinWidth="100"/>
    <Rectangle Fill="Blue" Margin="5" x:Name="NO2" RelativePanel.RightOf="O3" RelativePanel.Below="Pm10" MinHeight="100" MinWidth="100"/>
    <Rectangle Fill="Blue" Margin="5" x:Name="SO2" RelativePanel.RightOf="NO2" RelativePanel.Below="Pm10" MinHeight="100" MinWidth="100"/>
    <Rectangle Fill="Blue" Margin="5" x:Name="CO" RelativePanel.Below="O3" MinHeight="100" MinWidth="100" RelativePanel.AlignLeftWith="Pm25" RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True"/>
</RelativePanel>
```

But currently it looks like this :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For each row of rectangles, create a StackPanel with horizontal orientation and put the rectangles there.

Comment: I thought a horizontal stack panel can stretch vertical and a vertical one can horizontal only. I wonder if ```RelativePanel``` can achieve something like ```Grid.ColumnDefinitions```.

Comment: That’s not what relative panel is about. If you want grid-like behavior, use grid :)